# Swift watchOS companion app excluding parts of source code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I am currently struggling with building an watchOS Companion app alongside with an existing iOS App.

The progress is clear, the app is set up with their targets. But I am using Cocoapods that were built for arm64 technology and watchOS needs arm7.

I want to let the iOS app do all the work and just display some content on the watch companion app. But when I want to run an empty companion app, I get a lot of "module not found" errors, because it seems like the sourcecode has to be compiled completely for the watchOS system.

Since iOS build works fine currently, the watchOS fails - so is it possible to exclude the complete source code of the iOS app from the watchOS build and just use a little bit of shared code to get the necessary data from iOS to the watch?